# How should I use jr:itext logic to pull question answers and display them on a label in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I am trying to set up jr:itext logic to pull question answers from my app and display them on a label. I've followed the instructions in the CommCare [documentation](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Display+an+Answer+to+a+Previous+Question) and I've ensured the correct question path is being used for what I want to display. However on the device when I deploy my app all of my jr:itext logic shows as: `[itext:ql_notification_details/patient_type_choicenew-label]`

What is the best way to troubleshoot this error? Am I missing something in my jr:itext logic if I'm using exactly the logic displayed in the documentation?

Comment: Can you add the problematic label expression to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to display **answers** in labels then you should be able to directly reference them with something like this (where the question_id is ask_this)

`<output value="/data/ask_this" />`

If you're wanting to display the **label** of a choice in a later output (e.g. you're storing the choice value as a case property but it's different from the label used, and you need to selectively display the label again later then something like this:

`<output value="jr:itext(concat('ask_this-', /data/ask_this, '-label'))" />`

**edit**: if your question isn't at the top level then you'll need to reflect the path as such: folder/ask_this and /data/folder/ask_this
additionally, if you're wanting to save this as a hidden variable (e.g. using it in a calculate condition) then remove the "output value" wrapper and only use the bit between the double-quotes (not including the double-quotes)

That being said, *it looks like your "error" might actually be the output of a jr:itext phrase when the /data/here component is null*. Perhaps you've done what I did: set up a feed from a multi-choice question and thought you had an error, but it's actually because you've just not selected an answer yet?

Additionally, you might be missing a dash, either following "_choicenew" or preceding "label" I say this because if you've made the "null" error as I did, then I'd expect to see two dashes there, rather than one.

Other non-flattering troubleshooting for me was (quite some time into researching your question) reading to the end of the documentation and realizing that I'd not replaced all the "place-holder" text (I'd left in the first **question**).

Additionally, I opened up the raw XML via the "edit source XML" option to have a look at the way jr:itext is implemented in the raw code.

Comment: Derek this is a great answer to the question, indeed we were missing a dash. Thanks for all of this! this was so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that if you're saving the output (label text) **in a hidden value**, you do not need to include the "output value".

Instead, use the following:

```
jr:itext(concat('ask_this-', /data/ask_this, '-label'))
```